# How does Decommission (and Revolt) work with multiple permanents leaving the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A new Aether Revolt card, "Decommission", states: "If a permanent you controlled left the battlefield this turn, you gain 3 life".

[image: Decommission, a white instant spell that costs 2 generic mana and 1 white mana. It says: Destroy target artifact or enchantment. Revolt - If a permanent you controlled left the battlefield this turn, you gain 3 life.]

I suspect that would mean if you sacrificed 3 artifact tokens, then played decommission later on you would gain 9 life.

My confusion is that I would expect to see "for each permanent that left the battlefield this turn" to give the total of 9 life.  As it is written, I am thinking just 3, but is "each" implied?  Pretty basic question I guess.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

You gain exactly 3 life no matter how many of your permanents left the battlefield this turn (as long as it's at least one).

Your confusion as you describe it comes down to: "I expect this wording means {thing}. But if it *really* meant {thing} I'd expect it to use this other wording instead." Confusion like that is often a warning flag you've misread the card, and ought to check it again. MTG cards mean exactly what they say — if it meant "for each permanent" it'd say so.

The [Aether Revolt Release Notes](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/aether-revolt-release-notes-2017-01-06) state the following under the heading ***New Ability Word: Revolt***:

> - Revolt abilities check only whether a permanent you controlled left the battlefield this turn or not. They don’t apply multiple times if more than one permanent you controlled left the battlefield. They don’t check whether the permanent that left the battlefield is still in the zone it moved to.

Comment: Yeah, we were pretty close there, haha.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  AND thanks for the link to Aether Revolt Release Notes, that helps greatly!

Answer (score 4):

**You just gain 3 life**

Deathreap ritual says:

> Morbid — At the beginning of each end step, if a creature died this turn, you may draw a card.

if you look at the gatherer text for this card it says:

> You draw one card when the ability resolves, not one card per creature that died during the turn.

If you would draw a card for each creature that died it would say it like this:

> You draw a card for each creature that died this turn

There is an ability like this on armorcraft judge:

> When Armorcraft Judge enters the battlefield, draw a card for each creature you control with a +1/+1 counter on it.

Note that it specificly states each